# Linear regression with only unique value pairs?

Tags: regression, linear, software

Does it every make sense to discard duplicate value pairs and only perform the linear regression on unique value pairs? I've never heard of using such a method, so I wanted to see if I'm missing something, it there are situations where only unique value pairs might be desireable.

I ask because it appears to the default option when inserting a trend line in Tableau, which really caused a problem tracking down the cause when the model details didn't match my R lm output. There's an option to fix that, but I've

Comment: What do these duplicates represent?  Repeated descriptions of the same thing?  Independent observations with the same independent value?  Something else?

Comment: Independent observations with the same values. E.g. 

Person A has Var 1 = 5, Var 2 = 7. Person B has var 1 = 5 & Vart 2 = 7 as well. But the linear regression performed ignores Person B because it's a duplicate value pair. Depending on the distribution of the data & number of duplicate pairs, the results can be very different from a simple lm in R.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like an error in [Tableau](https://www.tableau.com/trial/tableau-software?utm_campaign_id=2017049&utm_campaign=Prospecting-CORE-ALL-ALL-ALL-ALL&utm_medium=Paid+Search&utm_source=Google+Search&utm_language=EN&utm_country=NOR&kw=tableau&adgroup=CTX-Brand-Core-EN-E&adused=324371786578&matchtype=e&placement=&gclid=CjwKCAjw2dD7BRASEiwAWCtCb42M-Uq5eQhj-z8L5Fy_TKV-tK3iuTtfY0NAxMr-hvy-QVbsUa-YExoCl2oQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds), a software I do not know. As a general option it does not make sense. Contact the company and ask them why they do this!